# Broaden pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data that looks like this:

```
Box,Code
Green,1221
Green,8391
Red,3709
Red,2911
Blue,9820
Blue,4530
```

Using a pandas dataframe, I'm wondering if it is possible to output something like this:

```
Box,Code1,Code2
Green,1221,8391
Red,3709,2911
Blue,9820,4530
```

My data always has an equal number of rows per 'Box'.

I've been experimenting with pivots and crosstabs (as well as stack and unstack) in pandas but haven't found anything that gets me to the 'broaden' result I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) for `list`s and then `DataFrame` constructor:

```
a = df.groupby('Box')['Code'].apply(list)
df = pd.DataFrame(a.values.tolist(), index=a.index).add_prefix('Code').reset_index()
print (df)
     Box  Code0  Code1
0   Blue   9820   4530
1  Green   1221   8391
2    Red   3709   2911
```

Or [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for new `Series` with [`pandas.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot.html):

```
g = df.groupby('Box').cumcount()
df = pd.pivot(index=df['Box'], columns=g, values=df['Code']).add_prefix('Code').reset_index()
print (df)
     Box  Code0  Code1
0   Blue   9820   4530
1  Green   1221   8391
2    Red   3709   2911
```

And similar solution with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df['g'] = df.groupby('Box').cumcount()
df = df.set_index(['Box', 'g'])['Code'].unstack().add_prefix('Code').reset_index()
print (df)
g    Box  Code0  Code1
0   Blue   9820   4530
1  Green   1221   8391
2    Red   3709   2911
```

Comment: Glad can help! Nice day!

Comment: You are indeed very fast! By the time I was ready to post, you had posted 5 mins back:) Anyway, great solutions

Comment: By the time I was figuring out a one solution, he has given three!

Comment: And I'd have been happy with any one of them! :)