# Broaden Pandas DataFrame with multiple source columns

Tags: python, pandas

Following on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45612552/broaden-pandas-dataframe), is it possible to perform a similar 'broaden' operation in pandas where there are multiple source columns per 'entity'?

If my data now looks like:

```
Box,Code,Category
Green,1221,Active
Green,8391,Inactive
Red,3709,Inactive
Red,2911,Pending
Blue,9820,Active
Blue,4530,Active
```

How do I most efficiently get to:

```
Box,Code0,Category0,Code1,Category1
Green,1221,Active,8391,Inactive
Red,3709,Inactive,2911,Pending
Blue,9820,Active,4530,Active
```

So far, the only solution I have been able to put together that 'works', is follow the example from the linked page and to create two separate DataFrames, one grouped by Box and Code, the other grouped by Box and Category, and then merge the two together by Box.

```
a = get_clip.groupby('Box')['Code'].apply(list)
b = get_clip.groupby('Box')['Category'].apply(list)
broadeneda = pd.DataFrame(a.values.tolist(), index = a.index).add_prefix('Code').reset_index()
broadenedb = pd.DataFrame(b.values.tolist(), index = b.index).add_prefix('Category').reset_index()
merged = pd.merge(broadeneda, broadenedb, on='Box', how = 'inner')
```

Is there a way to achieve this without broadening each column separately and merging at the end?

Comment: Will same color will appear in a row and each color has same rows? Or there could be missing data? If not, I will delete my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gourpby` + `cumcount`+`unstack`

```
df1=df.assign(n=df.groupby('Box').cumcount()).set_index(['Box','n']).unstack(1)
df1.columns=df1.columns.map('{0[0]}{0[1]}'.format) 
df1
Out[141]: 
       Code0  Code1 Category0 Category1
Box                                    
Blue    9820   4530    Active    Active
Green   1221   8391    Active  Inactive
Red     3709   2911  Inactive   Pending
```

Comment: To change this if I have more columns in my starting dataset, do I simply keep adding elements to the `df1.columns=df1.columns.map('{0[0]}{0[1]}'.format)` line? As in, if I add another column (e.g., arbitrarily called 'Subject'), would I just change the above line to: `df1.columns=df1.columns.map('{0[0]}{0[1]}{0[2]}'.format)`? (edit: removed comment formatting that did not render properly)

Comment: I experimented with the statement and I now realise that `'{0[0]}{0[1]}'` appear to be variable reference names, rather than positional references.

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**
Using `set_index`, `pipe`, and `set_axis`

```
df.set_index(['Box', df.groupby('Box').cumcount()]).unstack().pipe(
    lambda d: d.set_axis(d.columns.map('{0[0]}{0[1]}'.format), 1, False)
)

       Code0  Code1 Category0 Category1
Box                                    
Blue    9820   4530    Active    Active
Green   1221   8391    Active  Inactive
Red     3709   2911  Inactive   Pending
```

---

**Option 2**
Using `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(dict)

for a, *b in df.values:
    i = len(d[a]) // len(b)
    c = (f'Code{i}', f'Category{i}')
    d[a].update(dict(zip(c, b)))

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, 'index').rename_axis('Box')

       Code0 Category0  Code1 Category1
Box                                    
Blue    9820    Active   4530    Active
Green   1221    Active   8391  Inactive
Red     3709  Inactive   2911   Pending
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with iteration of sub-dataframes:

```
cols = ["Box","Code0","Category0","Code1","Category1"]
newdf = pd.DataFrame(columns = cols)    # create an empty dataframe to be filled
for box in pd.unique(df.Box):           # for each color in Box
    subdf = df[df.Box == box]           # get a sub-dataframe
    newrow = subdf.values[0].tolist()   # get its values and then its full first row
    newrow.extend(subdf.values[1].tolist()[1:3])    # add second and third entries of second row
    newdf = pd.concat([newdf, pd.DataFrame(data=[newrow], columns=cols)], axis=0)   # add to new dataframe

print(newdf)
```

Output:

```
     Box   Code0 Category0   Code1 Category1
0  Green  1221.0    Active  8391.0  Inactive
0    Red  3709.0  Inactive  2911.0   Pending
0   Blue  9820.0    Active  4530.0    Active
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that **same color will appear in a row** and **each color has same rows.** (Two important assumptions.) Thus, we can split the df into the odd part, `df[::2]`, and the even part, `df[1::2]`, and then merge it together.

```
pd.merge(df[::2], df[1::2], on="Box")

    Box     Code_x  Category_x  Code_y  Category_y
0   Green   1221    Active  8391    Inactive
1   Red     3709    Inactive    2911    Pending
2   Blue    9820    Active  4530    Active
```

One can rename it easily by resetting its columns.